# Renaming HDD's in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: hard-drive

I have 2 Samsung 1Tb G3 external drives and every time I start up my PC Ubuntu only detects 1 of them (presumably the one that boots quickest).  I assume it's because they're identical devices and that Ubuntu doesn't automatically designate drive letters etc like Windows. If I unplug both drives and put them in while the system is on then 1 is designated '1tb partition' while the other is named 'local disk'.  Is there a way to rename these drives so that they're visible at start up or do I need to change the names in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the drive's label using gparted.  The only thing that it has to be done from a LiveCD, since partitions have to be un-mounted to be able to have that accomplished.

Once you boot from the LiveCD, launch gparted, and right-click the partition and choose Properties. Click inside the Label field and enter a new name for the partition.  Once done click on apply, and you're done.

If you don't have gparted, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```